# Is it correct to use "either" and "too" interchangeably?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

The other day, I heard someone say:

> I want it either.

It comes strange to me. I'm usually used to hear/say:

> I want it too.

Is it grammatically correct to use either of them?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't hear, "I don't want it either." instead? It is not correct to say, "I want it either."

Comment: What JLG says. *I don't want it either* can sound like *I-o wannit either* in fast speech.

Comment: And "I don't want it either" does mean "too," "I don't want it, just as he doesn't."

Comment: @AndrewLeach: *I don;t want it either* may also mean *I want that no more than I want the other thing*  which can't be expressed with *too*. Murky waters; best not stirred.

Comment: @JLG Yes. I'm sure. That's why I asked the question. It seemed strange to me. Although, the person who said this, is not a native American.

Comment: _Either_ is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf). _Too_, on the other hand, can't occur with a strong negative: _*She doesn't like it, too._ Many of the little words that cause problems are NPIs because problem sentences tend to be full of negation.

Comment: OK. I just don't understand why the negative vote? Is there something wrong with the question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe they thought it was too easy. You yourself said that it sounded strange; so this would fit better on ELL. Or they think you just misheard. Maybe the person said "I want the tiger".

Comment: @MrLister I was arguing this with the person who said it. I told him that this sounds wrong, but I didn't have enough knowledge to prove it. That's the reason I asked this question. I think every question (even *easy* ones) should be documented. Maybe someday, someone needs one of them. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I want it either" is certainly incorrect, though "I want either" and "I don't want it either" are both standard and common.

I suspect that the person you heard use "I want it either" was modelling their use on the latter.

Here we're following a previous negative statement with agree in a later sentence, an extension of it's adverbial use in:

> I don't like him, and I don't like her either.

Some would object to "I don't want it either" (and even more to the more heavily elided "me either") that *neither* should be used instead. However, the use is certainly common. (Especially in American English, those who would insist on *neither* are more often British or Irish, though both opinions are found with all forms of English).

Indeed, ?"I don't want it, too" would here be the confusing case; arguably justifiable, but certainly at least strange.

That there is a common use of *either* that is similar to the form you heard, suggests that they are mistaking one use for the other, especially if they're a non-native speaker, as you say.

Answer (score 1):

No, the word "either" suggests a choice where "too" means "also".

Comment: So, the sentence "I want it either" is not correct, right?

Comment: @TecBrat, I think you should also cover the agreement-with-a-negative-statement meaning:  A: _I don't like Justin Bieber.  B: _I don't either_.  Your answer is incomplete otherwise, and, after all, the OP was probably referring to this sense of the word.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori I think you are correct. Another has already answered much better than my answer, and that better answer was selected, so I'll leave it as is. The "also not" connotation did not cross my mind earlier.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

No, they are not interchangeable for two reasons - grammar and meaning.

*"I want it too."* means that I want it.

If I heard someone say, *"I want it either"* I would think their usage strange but I would understand it to mean "I don't want it."

So the two have *opposite* meanings in my opinion.

**Explanation**

You will sometimes hear "Me either". This is invariably used to mean "Me neither."

Example

> **1.**
>
> "I don't want it to rain."
>
> "Me either."

This is quite common in informal speech and means "Neither do I."

By extension we can imagine the following conversation.

> **2.**
>
> "I don't want it to rain."
>
> "I want it either."

This has every appearance of being an over-generalisation of version 1. Probably by a non-native speaker.

P.S.

Apologies if I have duplicated some of what has already been said by others, including in comments. I hope I've added something and also successfully drawn together other people's explanations.